# How to identify a determiner in a sentence that uses 2 determiners

Tags: determiners

In the sentence, "This is a flower." How can we both say that the "a" refers to a general noun (flower), yet also account for the presence of the specific determiner, "this?"

Comment: The specification here is with respect to the specimen under the speaker's scrutiny and its location, not to its possible inherent distinctiveness.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence *this* is not 'attached' to *flower* and does not act as its determiner. It is a demonstrative pronoun acting as the subject of the sentence. The sentence may be paraphrased

> This thing here is a flower.  *unless you are from Alabama, where we say*
>   This-here thing is a flower.

Comment: If I could, +10 for the SAE version.  It's *much* more natural sounding.